# Why is iTerm2 is super slow on macOS BigSur?

Tags: mac, iterm2, macos-bigsur

I am super bummed out: My iTerm2 commands that were previously fast before Big Sur now crawl. Worse, when opening a new terminal it can take up to 50 seconds for the shell prompt to return.

What is happening here and how to I stop this from happening? I can SSH into a remote server and running commands (e.g., a basic `ls`) are still super snappy.

Is there some workaround for this?

Note, I tried setting “Session: Enable Session Restoration” to “No,” but this does not seem to have fixed it at all.

Comment: Odd. I would check if iTerm2 is fully up to date. If that doesn’t work, I recommend uninstalling it from the system with [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) and trying again. If all that fails, I recommend reporting an issue [to the developers of iTerm2 here](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues).

Comment: Interesting... today iterm2 is snappy when I type but opening a new terminal takes ages. Now tmux in iterm2 is still slow. The investigation continues. I'll update iTerm2 and maybe update tmux.

Comment: Bump. Same issue.

Comment: anything new with this?

Comment: Especially pasting longer text can take long. 200 lines took about 10 minutes in my case.

Comment: Updating my iTerm2 fixed the issue for me. `Build 3.4.8` is what solved mine.